# Parameterized Query not working PHP

Tags: php, sql, parameters

I have a pretty complex if/else statement system which in the end generates an SQL. However, in the end, I get a 'wrong parameter count' message and I have no idea what's going wrong? Hope you guys can help! My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";

if($bedrijfvariabele != " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." && $bedrijfvariabele != "") {

$params = array($bedrijfvariabele);
$sql .= " WHERE bedrijfsnaam = ?";

}


if($rubriekvariabele != " zoek op rubriek.." && $rubriekvariabele != "" && $bedrijfvariabele != " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." && $bedrijfvariabele != "") {

array_push($params, $rubriekvariabele);  
$sql .= " AND (hoofdrubriek = ? OR subrubrieken LIKE '%' + ? + '%')";

}


if($rubriekvariabele != " zoek op rubriek.." && $rubriekvariabele != "" && ($bedrijfvariabele == " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." || $bedrijfvariabele == "")) {

$params = array($rubriekvariabele);
$sql .= " WHERE (hoofdrubriek = ? OR subrubrieken LIKE '%' + ? + '%')";

}


if($plaatsvariabele != " zoek op plaatsnaam.." && $plaatsvariabele != "" && (($bedrijfvariabele != " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." && $bedrijfvariabele != "") || ($rubriekvariabele != " zoek op rubriek.." && 

$rubriekvariabele != ""))) {

array_push($params, $plaatsvariabele);  
$sql .= " AND plaats = ?";

}


if($plaatsvariabele != " zoek op plaatsnaam.."  && $plaatsvariabele != "" && (($bedrijfvariabele == " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." || $bedrijfvariabele == "")  && ($rubriekvariabele == " zoek op rubriek.." || 

$rubriekvariabele == ""))) {

$params = array($plaatsvariabele);
$sql .= " WHERE plaats = ?";

}


$sql .= " ORDER BY
(
(case when ID is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when username is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when password is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when voornaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when achternaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when telefoonnummerP is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when emailP is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when functie is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsnaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsslogan is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfslogo is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsfoto is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsfoto2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsfoto3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsfoto4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsomschrijving is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsspecialiteiten is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when bedrijfsgeschiedenis is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when openingstijden is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when kvk is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when straatnaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when huisnummer is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when postcode is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when plaats is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when nevenvestigingen is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when telefoonnummer is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when fax is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when email is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when website is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when twitter is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when facebook is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when youtube is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when linkedin is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when hoofdrubriek is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when subrubrieken is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when merken is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when diensten is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when productsoorten is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when brancheverenigingen is not null then 1 else 0 end)
) DESC, bedrijfsnaam LIMIT $start_from, 10";  

echo $sql;
print_r($params);

$rs_result = mysql_query($conn, $sql, $params);
```

The ECHO of the SQL gives this if I fill in one field:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE plaats = ? ORDER BY ( (case when ID is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when username is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when password is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when voornaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when achternaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when telefoonnummerP is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when emailP is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when functie is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsnaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsslogan is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfslogo is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsfoto is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsfoto2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsfoto3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsfoto4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsomschrijving is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsspecialiteiten is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when bedrijfsgeschiedenis is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when openingstijden is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when kvk is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when straatnaam is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when huisnummer is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when postcode is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when plaats is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when nevenvestigingen is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when telefoonnummer is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when fax is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when email is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when website is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when twitter is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when facebook is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when youtube is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when linkedin is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when hoofdrubriek is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when subrubrieken is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when merken is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when diensten is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when productsoorten is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when brancheverenigingen is not null then 1 else 0 end) ) DESC, bedrijfsnaam LIMIT 0, 10
```

Printing $params gives this:

```
Array ( [0] => \'s-Gravenmoer )
```

Comment: Please output your final generated querystring and add it to your question. This will help people determine whether there are problems with sql itself.

Comment: In some of your if statement blocks, you are overwriting the contents of your params with a new array. Perhaps you should use `array_push` in these cases as well.

Comment: @Asad, I've added that code for you.

Comment: @andy123, no that's not correct I'm afraid, in those cases the array first has to be created.

Comment: @andy124, I posted the result in my starting POST. As you can see, when I echo the SQL there is only one question mark, and the Array holds only one value. Still.... something is going wrong..

Answer (score 1):

In a couple places:

```
array_push($params, $rubriekvariabele);  
$sql .= " AND (hoofdrubriek = ? OR subrubrieken LIKE '%' + ? + '%')";

}
```

you have two parameters in the query, but only push a single value into the params array. You must have one push for every parameter.

Comment: Though that is true, it doesn't fix the problem.